# Visual studio code on ubuntu 20.04. c++ syntax checker does not work properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

I am trying to learn c++17 with Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 20.04 with the following `tasks.json`

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++2a",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And I have the following code, which compiles and runs well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    set<int> mSet;

    auto [iter, inserted] = mSet.insert(10);

    return 0;
}
```

But the syntax checker says that there is 3 problems.
[image]

I don't think that there is any problem with my code, so how can I make Visual Studio Code syntax checker work properly?

Comment: Usually visual studio code syntax highlighting stop working sometimes for no apparent reason, try restarting vscode or create a new file to write the code in.

Comment: @AntonEriksson I have just tried, but the problem stays.

Comment: It seems that IntelliSense misses the option for C++17 standard. The options in `tasks.json` are used to run the compiler, they have no influence on IntelliSense. I don't use MS plugin and prefer [`ccls`](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) + CMake. CMake can generate `compile_commands.json` that can be read by `ccls`. This way, you don't have to specify specify `-std` and `-I` paths manually for IntelliSense.

Comment: Installing the newest version of VScode could solve the problem. Which c++ extension do you use